# Excel: Comma separated values inside a cell - explode into more rows made with every combination

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to go from something like the first table to the second table:

[image]

...For the sake of using in a pivot table. I would like the first table to be on one sheet, and the second table to be another sheet, live-updating this "exploded" second table. I've been trying for a while and cannot get this to work. Any suggestions? The form I am using is outputting this list-type of comma separated values in single cells, and in this case it is not practical to do manually as there would be thousands of rows.

Comment: How big is the first table?  How many total possible values are there for each slot?

Comment: Take a look at the thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815321/text-to-rows-vba-excel)  Would need some tweaking but is a good place to start.

Comment: "live updating"?

Comment: The first table will be about 50 rows, and 10 columns. Only 2 columns have the comma lists. The first has a maximum of 14 elements, the second a maximum of 5 elements.

Comment: And "live updating" as in fill in sheet 1 with this data, sheet 2 has functions that will explode sheet 1 data into expanded rows, rather than overwriting sheet 1. As it is a form, sheet 1 will continue getting new rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the script [from the link gtwebb provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815321/text-to-rows-vba-excel). Here is the script:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    v = Split(Range("B" & i), ", ")
    c = c + UBound(v) + 1
Next i

For i = 2 To c
    Set r = Range("B" & i)
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(r, ", ")
    Dim j As Long
    r = arr(0)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
        r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
        r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next j
Next i

Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "@"
Dim k As Long, d As Long, s As Range, w As Variant

For k = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    w = Split(Range("C" & k), ", ")
    d = d + UBound(w) + 1
Next k

For k = 2 To d
    Set s = Range("C" & k)
    Dim arrb As Variant
    arrb = Split(s, ", ")
    Dim m As Long
    s = arrb(0)
    For m = 1 To UBound(arrb)
        Rows(s.Row + m & ":" & s.Row + m).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        s.Offset(m, 0) = arrb(m)
        s.Offset(m, -1) = s.Offset(0, -1)
        s.Offset(m, -2) = s.Offset(0, -2)
    Next m
Next k
End Sub
```

Since I only needed this for two columns I didn't bother with looping. The only things modified are that the script is repeated a second time, variables are changed, and the `Offset` parameter is changed.